# Running a cpp file on a Linux system creates a different file that does not execute?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn C++, but I am unable to get any code running.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello world!";
   return 0;
}
```

When I run this(or another file), it creates a different unrecognized file. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeQhF.jpg, picture 2) Then it gives the error at picture 1.

This is the launch.json:

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "cpp - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "cpp build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the task file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "cpp build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/cpp",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

The settings.json file is empty.

Both running without debugging and with it gives the same error. How can I fix this?

Ways that were tried:

1) Tried restarting both the application and the computer, doesn't work.

2) Tried using terminal to compile, run and debug the code. **It works**, but is there a way to do this over VS Code? (Should I open another question just for VS Code?)

```
# First, change your directory to the one that you want to use
# Run the following to compile in the same directory:

g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c++11 -g -o nameforexe source.cpp

# Change -std=c++11 to whatever version of c++ you want to use, and also the file names.
# To run it after this normally do this:

./nameforexe

# To debug, do:

gdb ./nameforexe

# After gdb opens, write "run" without " to run the file. 
# If there is a problem, it will tell you. If there isn't it will run normally.
```

Thanks to David C. Rankin for this. There is more info in the comments for this question.

3) Using CMake(suggested by dboy). I wasn't able to do this. After it says generated in the output section, I wasn't able to find the file to run the HelloWorld application. (Image 3 shows the files)

The CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project("HelloWorld")

set(SOURCE Helloworld.cpp)

add_executable("HelloWorldBuild" HelloWorld.cpp)
```

It didn't show any problems while compiling. CMake might be to advanced for me for now.

Comment: You’ve shown your launch configuration but now how you compile the file.

Comment: @rustyx Good point. That dialog looked very Windows 10 to me, my mistake.

Comment: The user is on Linux, but using VSCode

Comment: If you are running VS Code on Linux, then same caution about fighting any IDE. Just open any xterm, change to the directory containing your source file and `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c++11 -g -o nameforexe source.cpp` (change the standard as you need). Then you can run `./nameofexe` or run it in `gdb ./nameofexe` for debugging. When done debugging, replace `-g` with `-O3` (that's `dash Oh 3`).

Comment: The build task doesn't appear to get past preprocessing. You need to post your build task as well.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In my experience, it's rarely a fight wrt VS Code.

Comment: I don't know -- any time you have to start hacking `.json` files just to get something that should be trivial to work -- I call that a fight `:)` (Whoever came up with json and then applied that as a user configurable file should be dipped in honey and buried in an ant pile up to their neck....)

Comment: consider to use a build system, e.g. (cmake)[https://cmake.org/examples/] this will set everything you need for you to get your code get compiled.